VSTHRD003 with AuthenticationStateTask
After migrating from .Net 6 to .Net 8, I see the following warning:
VSTHRD003: Avoid awaiting or returning a Task representing work that was not started within your context as that can lead to deadlocks.
This pertains to AuthenticationStateTask where I do
[CascadingParameter] Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
    ...
}

The issue is that it seems to be the way Microsoft does it, see eg Expose the authentication state as a cascading parameter.
Is there a better way to do it that doesn't raise the warning? Or is this a special case where the warning should be turned off?

The approach used is the recommended one as it is provided and mentioned in the Microsoft document . You can refer to this document on handling VSTHRD003, which share how to manage this warning. In this case, since AuthenticationStateTask is provided by the Blazor framework, it’s designed to be safe to await directly

@JalpaPanchal So in this case it should indeed be safe to disregard the warning. As the warning comes from a Microsoft analyzer, it would be nice if it could handle expected cases like this.

as the code you are using is as per the Microsoft official document it is safe to avoid the warning. you could refer the mentioned document in my previous comment to how you can safely ignore the warning
